# increase memory for a perl script?

Tags: perl, replace

i have this script for perl, that is basically to read from a lookup file, but when i run it it seems does not work, but works with small input files, but big ones, it returns other carachteres.

if in equivalents i have the word Dog = can , if i have an input file with the word dog, it gets translated to Can.

what can i do to increase the memory capasity to run a 1gb input file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $LOOKUP , "<" , "equivalents.txt";
open my $LIST   , "<" , "input-text.txt";
open my $OUTPUT , ">" , "output.txt";

my %h;

while (<$LOOKUP>) {
    chomp;
    my ($k, $v) = split /\s*=\s*/;
    $h{$k} = $v;
}

while (<$LIST>) {
    s/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$h{$1} || "[$1]"/eg;
    print $OUTPUT $_;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "returns other characters" when you run with large files? How do you know you're running out of memory?

Comment: i guess, because when i run small input files, it works.   other characters as asian language, nor what is specified in the equivalents file.

Comment: That's not the behavior you would get if your process were running out of memory. How did you verify that the contents of the hash don't match what's in the input file?

Comment: is there a way to know it?, i am not a programmer, somebody made that script for me here in stack, but since is not possible to private message him, i need to ask everyone else.  thanks, do you know by the way how to solve it?

Comment: Just search the large input file for one of the strings that you think shouldn't be there. If it's in the file, problem solved; if not, run your code in the [debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) and try to figure out where it came from.

Comment: "returns other characters" sounds like an encoding issue, not a memory issue. Do you know the encoding of the files with Asian language characters? When you figure it out, open your input and output files with that encoding, e.g. `open my $LIST, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "input-text.txt"`

Comment: @mob you were right, it was utf16 and not ut8, but still i got some problems. but that would be another question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

While I understand what you want to do is increase the available memory for your program so that you can fit large files, you might want to consider looking for an alternative that doesn't put the whole file into memory if you want to operate on large files. The following module will demonstrate how to work on large files in Perl without using extra memory:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File

You might be able to start using it in your script in this manner:

```
use Tie::File;
tie @lookup, 'Tie::File', 'equivalents.txt' or die $@;

while (@lookup) {
    chomp;
    my ($k, $v) = split /\s*=\s*/;
    $h{$k} = $v;
}
```